# how to change pitch value of a LQFP footprint in Altium 20.0

Tags: pcb-design, altium

LQFP footprint-I want to change pitch value

Comment: You will have to create a new footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Either search for the required footprint in the supplied libraries or online libraries. If you can't find one suitable, then you have to generate one yourself. It's not too difficult and it is a useful skill - you'll find yourself need a specific footprint at some stage.

Comment: lol, "at some stage" is an euphemism.... I need specific footprint all the time ! Connectors are all different. It's indeed a very useful skill to master.